# How to Catch target=_blank redirections made from within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, http, iframe, cross-domain

I have a parent HTML page which contains a an iframe. The source page inside iframe is hosted on a different domain from parent domain. Inside the iframe in the site, there is an anchor tag with a target=_blank which is opening a new tab on my browser whenever clicked.

Instead I want to catch all these redirections/links made by the iframe, block these new tabs and console log the URL that the iframe was trying to redirect to.

Is there a way to do this in javascript/angular?

Comment: You can not touch a 3rd party domain with JavaScript so that is not going to help. You can look at sandboxing the iframe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#sandbox

Comment: No, that would be a huge security vulnerability. Imagine if websites could have an iframe with google sign in but redirect the token to a website, that would destroy all security.